# Invoking different operations one after another on single thread object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a situation where I want the same thread to perform multiple operations.
refer to code below:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public interface ISample
{
    void show();
}
class A : ISample
{
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside A");

    }
}

class B : ISample
{
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside B");

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISample aObj = new A();
        System.Threading.ThreadStart ts1 = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(aObj.show);
        System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(ts1);
        t1.Start();
        t1.Join();
        aObj = new B();
        t1.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Above code results in exception. I have seen lot of discussion on restarting the thread. In my case I want to perform multiple operations one after another on same thread. for me, I am looking out for solution to run different methods from different objects on same thread. All these objects are of classes implementing same interface as done in above code. Please suggest me best way to perform this. In other words, if a method is complete then same thread should start the method of another object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can try grouping all needed methods in a single anonymous delegate:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(
          () => {
               aObj.show();
               bObj.doStuff();
              });
 t1.Start();
```

Update:
If list of methods is not known beforehand, you can use [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class to run your methods on specific threads:

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Run);
 t1.Start();     
 Dispatcher.FromThread(t1).Invoke(()=>a.aObj.show());
```

Comment: The only limitation of this is that you need to know the methods to execute beforehand (for me it isn't clear if that's what the OP wants)

Comment: This will not work as I dont know upfront what all methods I will have to invoke on available thread object. Visualize a tree like structure and a thread for every node.

Comment: @NutanJayavant, updated answer with another option - using Dispatcher class.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the "Producer/Consumer" pattern (eg. with ConcurrentQueue and BlockingCollection if you can use .Net 4).

Such you have a worker thread that will be fed with jobs from your main thread. This is a very flexible solution for your scenario.